# What method or algorithm is used for computing Power Curve in cycling power data analysis?

Tags: time-series, games

Many cycling analytics apps, for example, Strava, TrainingPeaks or GoldenCheetah are offering the Power curve chart, computed from the cycling power time series data. I'm familiar with the curve meaning but I'm curious how the curve is computed from the time series.  I guess it is a more general statistical method, but my search for the literature with method description was not successful.

Example of the curve can be seen for example on [this Strava blog post](https://blog.strava.com/summit-power-analysis/).